# PL/pgSQL Query Plan Worse Inside Function Than Outside

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function that is running too slow. I've isolated which piece of the function is slow.. a small `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT image_group_id 
FROM programs.image_family fam 
JOIN programs.provider_file pf 
ON (fam.provider_data_id = pf.provider_data_id
AND fam.family_id = $1 AND pf.image_group_id IS NOT NULL) 
LIMIT 1
```

When I run the function this piece of SQL generates the following query plan:

```
Query Text: SELECT  image_group_id FROM programs.image_family fam JOIN programs.provider_file pf ON (fam.provider_data_id = pf.provider_data_id  AND fam.family_id = $1 AND pf.image_group_id IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1
Limit  (cost=0.56..6.75 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=3471.004..3471.004 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..594054.42 rows=96017 width=6) (actual time=3471.002..3471.002 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on image_family fam  (cost=0.00..391880.08 rows=96023 width=6) (actual time=3471.001..3471.001 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: ((family_id)::numeric = '8419853'::numeric)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 19204671
        ->  Index Scan using "IX_DBO_PROVIDER_FILE_1" on provider_file pf  (cost=0.56..2.11 rows=1 width=12) (never executed)
              Index Cond: (provider_data_id = fam.provider_data_id)
              Filter: (image_group_id IS NOT NULL)
```

When I run the selected query in a query tool (outside of the function) the query plan looks like this:

```
Limit  (cost=1.12..3.81 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: pf.image_group_id
  Buffers: shared hit=11
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..14.55 rows=5 width=6) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: pf.image_group_id
        Inner Unique: true
        Buffers: shared hit=11
        ->  Index Only Scan using image_family_family_id_provider_data_id_idx on programs.image_family fam  (cost=0.56..1.65 rows=5 width=6) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: fam.family_id, fam.provider_data_id
              Index Cond: (fam.family_id = 8419853)
              Heap Fetches: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=6
        ->  Index Scan using "IX_DBO_PROVIDER_FILE_1" on programs.provider_file pf  (cost=0.56..2.58 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: pf.provider_data_id, pf.provider_file_path, pf.posted_dt, pf.file_repository_id, pf.restricted_size, pf.image_group_id, pf.is_master, pf.is_biggest
              Index Cond: (pf.provider_data_id = fam.provider_data_id)
              Filter: (pf.image_group_id IS NOT NULL)
              Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning time: 0.809 ms
Execution time: 0.100 ms
```

If I disable sequence scans in the function I can get a similar query plan:

```
Query Text: SELECT  image_group_id FROM programs.image_family fam JOIN programs.provider_file pf ON (fam.provider_data_id = pf.provider_data_id  AND fam.family_id = $1 AND pf.image_group_id IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1
    Limit  (cost=1.12..8.00 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=3855.722..3855.722 rows=0 loops=1)
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..660217.34 rows=96017 width=6) (actual time=3855.721..3855.721 rows=0 loops=1)
            ->  Index Only Scan using image_family_family_id_provider_data_id_idx on image_family fam  (cost=0.56..458043.00 rows=96023 width=6) (actual time=3855.720..3855.720 rows=0 loops=1)
                  Filter: ((family_id)::numeric = '8419853'::numeric)
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 19204671
                  Heap Fetches: 368
            ->  Index Scan using "IX_DBO_PROVIDER_FILE_1" on provider_file pf  (cost=0.56..2.11 rows=1 width=12) (never executed)
                  Index Cond: (provider_data_id = fam.provider_data_id)
                  Filter: (image_group_id IS NOT NULL)
```

The query plans are different where the Filter functions are for the Index Only Scan. The function has more `Heap Fetches` and seems to treat the argument as a string casted to a `numeric`.

Things I've tried:

1. Increasing statistics (and running vacuum/analyze)
2. Calling the problematic piece of SQL in another function with language `SQL`
3. Add another index (the one that its using now to perform an INDEX ONLY scan)
4. Create a CTE for the image_family table (this did help performance but would still do a sequence scan on the image_family instead of using the index so still, too slow)
5. Change from executing raw SQL to using an `EXECUTE ... INTO .. USING` in the function.

Makeup of the two tables:

**image_family:**

```
provider_data_id: numeric(16)
family_id:        int4
```

(rest omitted for brevity)

- unique index on `provider_data_id`
- index on `family_id`
- I recently added a unique index on `(family_id, provider_data_id)` as well

Approximately 20 million rows here. Families have many provider_data_ids but not all provider_data_ids are part of families and thus aren't all in this table.

**provider_file:**

```
provider_data_id numeric(16)
image_group_id   numeric(16)
```

(rest omitted for brevity)

- unique index on `provider_data_id`

Approximately 32 million rows in this table. Most rows (> 95%) have a Non-Null `image_group_id`.

Postgres Version 10

How can I get the query performance to match whether I call it from a function or as raw SQL in a query tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exhibited in this line:

```
Filter: ((family_id)::numeric = '8419853'::numeric)
```

The index on `family_id` cannot be used because `family_id` is compared to a `numeric` value. This requires a cast to `numeric`, and there is no index on `family_id::numeric`.

Even though `integer` and `numeric` both are types representing numbers, their internal representation is quite different, and so the indexes are incompatible. In other words, the cast to `numeric` is like a function for PostgreSQL, and since it has no index on that functional expression, it has to resort to a scan of the whole table (or index).

The solution is simple, however: use an `integer` instead of a `numeric` parameter for the query. If in doubt, use a cast like

```
fam.family_id = $1::integer
```